# Residuals vs. fitted values graph in R

Tags: r

I am going to plot residuals vs. fitted values but the graph show the number of years and connect together. How can I remove the number of year and change it to dots.

```
setwd("/Users/lok19_000/Desktop/project")
z = read.csv("data4.csv" , header = F)
names(z) = c("Date","Rate")
attach(z)
ts_rate <- ts(Rate,start=c(2010),frequency = 12)
lts_rate<-log(ts_rate)
fit3=tslm(lts_rate ~ trend + season)
windows()
plot(fit3$fitted.values,fit3$residuals,main="residuals vs.     
fitted",xlab="Fitted Value",ylab="Residual value")
abline(h=0,lwd=2,col = "red3")
```

[Please take a look of the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIKXO.png)

Comment: `Rate`? `tslm`? So not reproducible. And I'm guessing you have `attach()`-ed a dataframe. At any rate, `trend + season` cannot be reproduced either.

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: Why don't you use the dput function on z and include the output in your question.  Then readers can run the rest of your code and help you.